# How to require jQuery in Express app with EJS template engine

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, requirejs, ejs

I'm using ExpressJS for web development and EJS as template engine.
I want to know if there is any convenient way of requiring jQuery to work on my EJS template.
I could add a script tag in one of the partial i.e footer.ejs and include this everywhere, but that would result in the jQuery being loading in all modules ( I'd be using jQuery only in few, when needed ).
So, is there way where in I could require jQuery only in specific modules and not add it as a common file.

I read about `shim` way of including in specific modules [here](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-shim), but dint quite understand how it could be applied to my settings ( express app with ejs templates ).

Any reasonable illustration on how to achieve this is much appreciated.

Many thanks.

```
footer.ejs
//This image shows my footer partial which has jQuery as common inclusion.
```

[[image: This image shows my footer partial which has jQuery as common inclusion.]

```
form.js
//This is my script file which has jQuery as dependency
```

[[image: This is my script file which has jQuery as dependency ]]

```
form.ejs
//This is how the form-validation script is being included in form template
```

[image: This is how the form-validation script is being included in form template]

Comment: My guess is that your `form.js` is loaded before jquery is

Comment: Please don't post script as screenshots

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind. But, may I know why?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to enable `extractScripts` first

```
app.set("layout extractScripts", true);
```

and then, using `<%- script %>` in your layout to inject all scripts in view

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <script src="/path/to/jquery"></script>
        <script src="/path/to/other/lib"></script>
        ...

        <%- script %>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this might work for me. I'll have to do some reading on this.
Thanks for showing this to me.
Cheers!